# Decoupling Modules in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, frontend, single-page-application

I want to decouple my application modules so that each modules can be developed individually. I use React, Redux and React Router and I think routing place a major role here. I also want to retain SPA (no page reload) feature of the application. Should I have different html files? Can I bundle my source JS files separately?

[image]

My thoughts are broad so I want to narrow it down to the best possible solutions.

With the current structure I have above, Im worried that my single source JS files will have a huge file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach to deal with large bundle files to use webpack for [code splitting](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) your application:

https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7#code-splitting-with-es6

The [kyt-starter-universal](https://github.com/NYTimes/kyt-starter-universal/blob/master/src/routes/index.js) repository has an example:

```
const importHome = (nextState, cb) => {
  System.import('../components/Home')
    .then(module => cb(null, module.default))
    .catch((e) => { throw e; });
};

...

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute getComponent={importHome} />
    ...
  </Route>
);
```

With webpack 2, rather than importing the modules normally, `System.import` will let webpack know to create a separate chunk for that module and its dependencies. Webpack 1 also has code splitting using `require.ensure`

More reading:

http://moduscreate.com/code-splitting-for-react-router-with-es6-imports/
https://medium.com/@puppybits/webpack-code-splitting-by-routes-92f96cf733f2#.v1mxmc3ty
http://jonathancreamer.com/advanced-webpack-part-2-code-splitting/
http://blog.netgusto.com/asynchronous-reactjs-component-loading-with-webpack/

Answer (score 0):

Very much with agree @DTing that using webpack is your best bet here. 
Webpack includes an optimizer that understands how to split n modules into m bundles. It generates separate js files for each chunk alongside the main bundle and loads them when you call require.

Few more resources that was helpful for me for understading the fundamentals here..

A) [automatic-code-splitting-for-react-router-w-es6-imports](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/automatic-code-splitting-for-react-router-w-es6-imports-a0abdaa491e9#.aqw22hp7h)

B) [Discussions on setting up code splitting in Webpack and React Router](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2433)

C)[On why the JS bundle for the Vector.im web app is too big, and ways it could potentially be improved using code splitting and app structure changes. A good example of ways to improve bundle sizes](https://github.com/vector-im/vector-web/issues/2498)

D) [getting-started-with-webpack-2](https://blog.madewithenvy.com/getting-started-with-webpack-2-ed2b86c68783#.rs6qlucaa)